# bash using variables in mysql from cmdline

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, variables

Say I have a number of similar mysql databases, where one table consists of users, which I want to query, while the name of the specific table is also variable.

I would say I need something similar, but it gives me a hard time to get the quotes rigth:

`user_id = $(mysql --user=$dba --password=$dbp $dbn -e "SELECT id FROM ${user_tbl} WHERE username = \"guest\"")`

Addition:
Ok, now knowing what the initial query should have been, comes the other question, how to update a field again using a variable for the tabelname.

`mysql --user=$dba --password=$dbp $dbn -e "UPDATE ${user_tbl} SET password=${pass} WHERE username = 'guest'"` 
gives the following error:
Unknown column 'some_encrypted_pass' in 'field list'

Comment: `... WHERE username = "guest"` is not valid in any SQL. Simply making that a valid SQL would have solved your problem instantly. `... WHERE username = 'guest'`

Answer (score 1):

```
user_id=$(mysql --user=$dba --password=$dbp $dbn -e "SELECT id FROM ${user_tbl} WHERE username = 'guest'")
```

you should use single quote to search `guest` string.

btw, why are you using that method, simply run mysqli_query and get value in array [with fetch methods] ? that will be better and more secure and reliable.

Comment: Thank you. Been trying so many combinations of double quotes, single quotes with or without backslashes, that I nearly lost my sight.

Comment: yes, I thought you are using PHP code, my bad. but you can use php for easy coding if you know it.

Comment: Well, in the end I concluded that variables for tablenames are possible to some extend, and impossible beyond.
So it may be time to change for PHP/Perl/Python or the like for this sort of system utilities.
I was using bash :)